# How to create nested list of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to create `Product` instance in Javascript and than to pass it to the server using `[webmethod]`.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetProduct(Product product)
{    
     // i want a product instance    
}
```

Following is `Product` class that i'm trying to create:

```
public class Product
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am being able to create `Type` and `Foo` but not `List<Bar>` in Javascript: (see my comments in the code for more details)

Javascript

```
function setProduct() {
    var product = {};
    product.Type = {};
    product.Foo = {};

    product.Type.ID = 'typeID';
    product.Foo.ID = 'fooID';
    product.Foo.Color = 'fooColor';

    //here is my question how can create List<Bar> Bars and add it to product item???

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/SetProduct",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: "{product:" + JSON.stringify(product) + "}",
    });
}
```

Comment: What does _"I'm having trouble"_ mean?  What's your question?

Comment: please see my comments in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't know what a `List<T>` is. It only knows how to make arrays. So you'll have to construct an array of `Bar`s and pass that in the JSON.

Fortunately, it's an easy fix:

```
product.Bars = [
    { Name: "bar 1" },
    { Name: "bar 2" },
    { Name: "bar 3" },
];
```

---

The above is probably all you need. I'm pretty sure ASP.NET will be smart enough to convert that `Bar[]` into a `List<Bar>` automagically, but just in case it isn't:

```
public class Product
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Then if you still want `List<T>` functionality, just convert the array to a List in your WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetProduct(Product product)
{    
     var list = product.Bars.ToList();
     product.Bars = list;
     return product;
}
```

Now you can still access those nice `List<T>` methods:

```
((List<Bar>)product).Add(new Bar() { Name = "bar 4" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create an array
product.Bars = [];

// add an element to the array
product.Bars.push({
    Name: "Foo"
});
```

alternatively you can initialize the array with elements as well:

```
// create and initialize array
product.Bars = [{Name:"Foo"}, {Name:"Bar"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, and add the items to the array with `array.push`. Eg :

```
product.Bars = [];
product.Bars.push({ Name: "foo" });
```